# How to animate an image between states

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, html5-canvas

I have some text that I would like to animate between a few states ***on hover***.

Ideally, would like to mimic the below gif (I have the various states of the text).

[image]

Can anyone point me in the direction of how I would do this? I'm thinking using `setInterval` on html/css properties could work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letter-spacing` is an CSS-animatable property, so you can set up a simple CSS keyframe to get this effect. No JS needed. For example:

```css
span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  animation-name: space-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.g1 { animation-delay: 0.5s; }
.g2 { animation-delay: 0s; }
.g3 { animation-delay: 1.3s; }
.g4 { animation-delay: 0.8s; }

@keyframes space-out {
  0% { letter-spacing: 0; }
  20% { letter-spacing: 1.2em; }
  50% { letter-spacing: 1.2em; }
  60% { letter-spacing: 0.3em; }
  90% { letter-spacing: 0.8em; }
  100% { letter-spacing: 0.8em; }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="g1">Haus</span><span class="g2">der</span>
  <span class="g3">kun</span><span class="g4">st</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems a `letter-spacing` animation.

Here is a simplified example that you can elaborate considering more animation states:

```css
.box {
 display:inline-block;
 font-size:25px;
}
.box span {
  padding:0 2px;
  animation:change 1s infinite alternate;
}
.box span:last-child {
  animation-delay:0.5s;
}

@keyframes change {
 from{letter-spacing:0px}
 to{letter-spacing:15px}
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span>Some</span>
<span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution, I will upvote as the answer. It would be good to see it act identical to the gif, I'm not sure if that's possible though?

Comment: @JordanMiguel it's possible ;) Let me try to make it closer but the gif is too fast :p

Comment: Ok! :) Thanks a lot!